# MongoDB query with multiple criteria using php

Tags: php, mongodb

In terminal, this returns what I want:

```
db.test.find({"sessions": {"$gt":5}, "n_friends":{"$lt":5}});
```

However in PHP, I have not been successful yet.
The last thing I've tried looked like this:

```
    $query = $collection->find( array(
        'sessions' => array( '$gt' => 1 ), 
        '$and' => array('n_friends' => array( '$lt' => 50 ) ) ) );
```

Comment: Nevermind I got it.

Basically I just realized that `:` becomes `=>` in PHP, and the `{}` become `array()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overcomplicating it :)

```
<?php
$query = array(
    'sessions' => array( '$gt' => 1 ),
    'n_friends' => array( '$lt' => 50 ),
);
```